# Novel about a sorceress called Rumour who has spells woven into her hair

Tags: story-identification, novel, magic

Novel about a sorceress called Rumour who has spells woven into her hair. Her hair is long and black. Her hair is cut off for some reason and her friends are tortured by being roasted in a cage over a fire with a really graphic description of cooking them. Fat sizzling as they were slow cooked and the skin split which made the meat tender.

I read it in the mid to late 90s but I think it's from the 80s.

There was a character called the Fisher King who everyone was afraid of. He had a barbed penis.
It has a medieval vibe in terms of clothing, weapons and social structure.

Comment: Can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) and [edit] in some more details? For example when did you read this? Was it new at the time? Any specific plot elements you remember?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [Sorceress](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/31572628-sorceress) by Sarah Rayne. It features a character named Rumour who's a sorceress and who weaves spells into her hair.

> ‘Better,’ said Rumour and, slowly and deliberately, every movement
>   studied, she began to dance, shaking her hair out so that it whirled
>   about her head, silken and perfumed. The feel of it brushing her
>   shoulders gave her courage, for she had twined into her hair a great
>   deal of strength and a great many subtle spells.

In a later scene, various characters are roasted in a cage.

[image]